# Memory error utilizing numpy arrays Python

Tags: python, function, numpy, out-of-memory, numpy-ndarray

My original `list_` function has over 2 million lines of code and I get a memory error when I run the code that calculates . Is there a way I could could go around it. The `list_` down below isa  portion fo the actual numpy array.

Pandas data:

```
import pandas as pd
import math
import numpy as np
bigdata = 'input.csv'
data =pd.read_csv(Daily_url, low_memory=False)
#reverses all the table data values
data1 = data.iloc[::-1].reset_index(drop=True)
list_= np.array(data1['Close']
```

[image]

Code:

```
number = 5
list_= np.array([457.334015,424.440002,394.795990,408.903992,398.821014,402.152008,435.790985,423.204987,411.574005,
404.424988,399.519989,377.181000,375.467010,386.944000,383.614990,375.071991,359.511993,328.865997,
320.510010,330.079010,336.187012,352.940002,365.026001,361.562012,362.299011,378.549011,390.414001,
400.869995,394.773010,382.556000])

def rolling_window(a, window):
    shape = a.shape[:-1] + (a.shape[-1] - window + 1, window)
    strides = a.strides + (a.strides[-1],)
    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=shape, strides=strides)

std = np.std(rolling_window(list_, number), axis=1)
```

Error Message: `MemoryError: Unable to allocate 198. GiB for an array with shape (2659448, 10000) and data type float64`

Full length of the error message:

```
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-df0ab5649b16> in <module>
      5     return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=shape, strides=strides)
      6 
----> 7 std1 = np.std(rolling_window(PC_list, number), axis=1)

<__array_function__ internals> in std(*args, **kwargs)

C:\Python3.7\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py in std(a, axis, dtype, out, ddof, keepdims)
   3495 
   3496     return _methods._std(a, axis=axis, dtype=dtype, out=out, ddof=ddof,
-> 3497                          **kwargs)
   3498 
   3499 

C:\Python3.7\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py in _std(a, axis, dtype, out, ddof, keepdims)
    232 def _std(a, axis=None, dtype=None, out=None, ddof=0, keepdims=False):
    233     ret = _var(a, axis=axis, dtype=dtype, out=out, ddof=ddof,
--> 234                keepdims=keepdims)
    235 
    236     if isinstance(ret, mu.ndarray):

C:\Python3.7\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py in _var(a, axis, dtype, out, ddof, keepdims)
    200     # Note that x may not be inexact and that we need it to be an array,
    201     # not a scalar.
--> 202     x = asanyarray(arr - arrmean)
    203 
    204     if issubclass(arr.dtype.type, (nt.floating, nt.integer)):

MemoryError: Unable to allocate 198. GiB for an array with shape (2659448, 10000) and data type float64
```

Comment: In fact with large processing, you might consider minimize to n parts, or put it in file and enumerate it line by line.

Comment: @TấnNguyên The `list_` values are within a csv file and i obtain the values with pandas and then I type cast the pandas column to a numpy array.

Comment: These have several ways to go, when you obtain the value with pandas, have you optimized any loading? Such as, you could load column you use, and process it line by line. You might check here for more detail: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/scale.html

Comment: @TấnNguyên I have already done those I will update the details for you

Comment: Pandas already has support for various data aggregation of rolling windows via `df.rolling(n)`. [Here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) is the documentation for it!

Answer (score 0):

Do us the favor of referencing your previous related questions (at least 2).  I happened to recall seeing something similar and so look up your previous questions.

Also when asking about an error, show the full traceback (if possible).  It should us (and **you**) identify where the problem occurs, and narrow down possible reasons and fixes.

With the sample `list_` (why such a bad name for a numpy array?) of only (35,) shape, the `rolling_window` array isn't that large. Plus it's a `view`:

```
In [90]: x =rolling_window(list_, number)
In [91]: x.shape
Out[91]: (26, 5)
```

However an operation on this array might produce a copy, boosting memory use.

In [96]: np.std(x, axis=1)
Out[96]:
array([22.67653383, 10.3940773 , 14.60076482, 13.82801944, 13.68038469,
12.54834004, ...
8.07511323])
In [97]: _.shape
Out[97]: (26,)

`np.std` does:

```
std = sqrt(mean(abs(x - x.mean())**2))
```

`x.mean(axis=1)` is one value per row, but

```
In [102]: x.mean(axis=1).shape
Out[102]: (26,)
In [103]: (x-x.mean(axis=1, keepdims=True)).shape
Out[103]: (26, 5)
In [106]: (abs(x-x.mean(axis=1, keepdims=True))**2).shape
Out[106]: (26, 5)
```

produces an array as big as `x`, and will be a full copy; not a strided virtual copy.

Does the error message shape make sense?  `(2659448, 10000)`  Is your `window` size 10000?  And the expected number of windows the other value?

`198. GiB` is a reasonable number given that dimension:

```
In [94]: 2659448*10000*8/1e9
Out[94]: 212.75584
```

I'm not going test your code with a large enough array to produce a memory error.

`as_strided` is a nice way of generating moving windows, and fast - but it easily blows up the memory usage.

Comment: Just wondering, since this asks for a window couldn't the OP better use `np.memmap` to reduce RAM usage?

Comment: @CodeNoob, `memmap` can be used for arrays the user creates, but the problem is with arrays that `np.std` creates as part of its calculation.

Comment: @hpaulj I have updated the details of the issue including the pandas library and how I achieve the data. I have also posted a full length of the error message. i see that there is not much of a way I could go through an indexed numpy array with a memory function. Is there any other library that would let me go through such large list values and perform mathematical equations with?

Comment: You could calculate this `std` on chunks.  I don't know how many.  100 chunks may cut the memory requirement to 2gB each.  If I recall correctlly originally you were iterating over all 2659448 windows, one at a time.  Iterating 100 times on size 26595 windows might be a reasonable compromise.

Comment: @hpaulj ok I will try to break it into chunks is there a way I could index numpy just like a list a list `list[:n]`.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, there are two ways to deal with "cannot allocate 198GiB of memory":

- Process the data in chunks, or line-by line.

  Your algorithm appears to be suitable for this; rather than reading the data all at once, rewrite the `rolling_window` function so that it loads the initial window (first `n` lines of the file), then repeatedly drops one line and reads one line from the file. That way, you'll never have more than `n` lines of memory and it'll all work fine.

  If it's a local file, it can be kept open during the whole calculation, which is easiest. If it's a remote object, you may find connections timing out; if so, you may need to either copy the data to a local file, or use the relevant seek/offset parameter to reopen the file for each additional line (or each additional chunk, which you buffer locally).
- Alternately, buy (rent) a machine with more than 200 GiB of memory; machines with over 1 TiB of memory are available off-the-shelf at AWS (and presumably GCP and Azure; or for direct purchase).

  This is especially suitable if you're reasonably sure your requirements won't grow further and you just need to get this one job done. It'll save you rewriting your code to handle this, but it's not a sustainable solution in a longer term.

Comment: Ok thank you got it will try to work on that.

Comment: I have been trying to comprehend it into chunks but doesnt seem to work is there a way i could organize it that way.

Comment: The `pandas.read_csv` function has `iterator` and `chunksize` options. Perhaps experiment with them on a small file with `iterator=True, chunksize=3` or similar to get a feel for how it works?

Comment: In terms of calculating standard deviation based on chunks, take a look at the [`runstats` library](https://pypi.org/project/runstats/).

Comment: sorry for bothering too much but I have tried chunk sizes and such and it doesnt really help instead I tried to implement multiprocessing and divide the for loop into chunks. I have made an issue about it [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65854842/multiprocessing-an-array-in-chunks). If you could take a quick look at it would be appreciated.

Comment: Multiprocessing probably won't help; the trick with chunks is to make sure that you only read in one at a time and make sure it's gone before reading the next one — don't put it in a list or anything. The `pandas.read_csv` function already returns it as an iterator, but you must be sure to process it directly in a `for` loop, so that you really do have just one in memory at a time.