# Multiprocessing an array in chunks

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multiprocessing, numba

I have broken my standard deviation function into small chunks of `std_1, std_2, std_3` etc. to optimize my code to make it run faster. Since I have over 2 million arrays on my main numpy array `PC_list`. I have used the numba, numpy arrays and multi processing to make the code run faster however I do not see any performance difference in the way even doe the code is broken into pieces from the main function. It takes about 57 seconds for the main function to process and the divided function to compute which makes me believe that the multi processing does not work. Although it takes about 12 to 13 seconds to go through each divided function `std1, std2, std3, std4, std5 std6`. The `PC_list` array posted below is a short bit of the actual array. I have also tried running the main function solely on numpy but it hasn't worked and has given me a memory issue, link to previouse issue [prev issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65768068/memory-error-utilizing-numpy-arrays-python/65783521?noredirect=1#comment116407526_65783521).

PC_list array:

```
number = 5
PC_list= np.array([457.334015,424.440002,394.795990,408.903992,398.821014,402.152008,435.790985,423.204987,411.574005,
404.424988,399.519989,377.181000,375.467010,386.944000,383.614990,375.071991,359.511993,328.865997,
320.510010,330.079010,336.187012,352.940002,365.026001,361.562012,362.299011,378.549011,390.414001,
400.869995,394.773010,382.556000])
```

Main function(entire list length used) takes 58 seconds to run:

```
@njit
def std():
    std1 = np.array([PC_list[i:i+number].std() for i in range(0, (len(PC_list)-number))])
    return(std1)
```

Time it takes for each chunk to run:
[image]

multi processing functions(list split into chunks) takes 58 seconds to run

```
divide = (len(PC_list)-number)/6
@njit
def std_1():
    print("std1")
    std1 = np.array([PC_list[i:i+number].std() for i in range(0, round(divide))])
    return(std1)
@njit
def std_2():
    print("std2")
    std2 = np.array([PC_list[i:i+number].std() for i in range(round(divide), round(divide*2))])
    return(std2)
@njit
def std_3():
    print("std3")
    std3 = np.array([PC_list[i:i+number].std() for i in range(round(divide*2), round(divide*3))])
    return(std3)
@njit
def std_4():
    print("std4")
    std4 = np.array([PC_list[i:i+number].std() for i in range(round(divide*3), round(divide*4))])
    return(std4)
@njit
def std_5():
    print("std5")
    std5 = np.array([PC_list[i:i+number].std() for i in range(round(divide*4), round(divide*5))])
    return(std5)
@njit
def std_6():
    print("std6")
    std6 = np.array([PC_list[i:i+number].std() for i in range(round(divide*5), round(divide*6))])
    return(std6) 
#setting up the multi processing vars     
p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=std_1)
p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=std_2)
p3 = multiprocessing.Process(target=std_3)
p4 = multiprocessing.Process(target=std_4)
p5 = multiprocessing.Process(target=std_5)
p6 = multiprocessing.Process(target=std_6)
#running the multi processes 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p3.start()
    p4.start()
    p5.start()
    p6.start()
std1 = std_1()
std2 = std_2()
std3 = std_3()
std4 = std_4()
std5 = std_5()
std6 = std_6()
#Combinning all the standard deviation chunks together
std = np.concatenate((std1, std2, std3, std4, std5, std6))
```

Comment: What sort of runtime are you looking for? In many situations, 58s is just fine. What's your deadline?

Comment: BTW, the problem with the code is that you start 6 processes, but then also do all the calculations in the main one, with `std1 = std_1()` and so on.

Comment: @sabik I was expecting the whole process to finish in about 13 seconds. . How could i run all the processes at once then ?

Comment: You already run them all at once, but then you never collect the results from `p1`..`p6` and instead run the functions again in the main process. You need to read through your code and understand what each line is doing.

Comment: For getting results back from the processes, probably best to switch to [multiprocessing.pool](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool), which has all the machinery for getting parameters to and results from the actual functions being run. Be careful not to run the whole array through the machinery (it'd be slow), but otherwise it'll do most of the work for you.

Comment: In terms of 13s vs 58s, does that make an actual difference in terms of your business objectives? You can optimise forever, but is it going to make any difference in the end?